# Suppress Github references from commit message to PR

Tags: github

I have a branch in which I (automatically) apply some patches from pull requests.

I do so by committing the PRs' diff and have a commit message like this one

> PATCHED | Apply patch https://github.com/randombit/botan/pull/386

Now every time I do that in a commit that is hosted on Github, the PR gets referenced.

In my case this does not add any value to the PR itself, as it is referenced multiple times and not part of any discussion. Can I suppress this referencing from my commit message?

---

This is what happens when I create a bunch of different commits that have a PR url in the commit message:

[image]

Here you can verify that totally unrelated commits create references just by commit message parsing:

- https://github.com/webmaster128/dummy-github-ref-test
- https://github.com/randombit/botan/pull/386

Comment: @ChrisBeck I reorganized the question based on your comment, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

One simple thing you could do is, not write the reference to the PR # in a way that github will parse it as such.

So, instead of

> https://github.com/randombit/botan/pull/386

or

> #386

you could try writing just

> Pull request number 386

The fanciest thing that I could imagine doing is,

> https://myserver.com/botan/pull/386

and then setup your server to redirect such queries to your github page... That way, you still get a clickable hyperlink in the commit messages, but you subvert github's referencing. It's a lot more effort than the alternatives though.

Edit: [This](https://help.github.com/articles/writing-on-github/#references) is the most complete documentation I could find about github references in gfm. [Here](https://help.github.com/articles/closing-issues-via-commit-messages/) is some additional info about the parsing they do for 'closing issues via commit messages'. I couldn't find any more detailed documentation.

Comment: Workaround number two is not too uninteresting my case, thanks.

Answer (score -1):

> Now every time I do that in a commit that is hosted on Github, the PR gets referenced.

This is what pull request is all about, any change made to the given branch is added to the PR and any contributor is being notified about it.

---

You will keep getting notification until you will do one of the following

#### Close the pull request

Once the pull request is closed it will not track changes made to the given branch

---

#### Unsubscribe

Click on unsubscribe option in the pull request
[image]

---

#### Close the pull request

Close the pull request by accepting or declining it

Comment: I am not talking about commits on the PR branch but any commit in any branch in any repository from any user that just have the PR url in the commit message.

Comment: Read this article (mostly the last part of it:
https://github.com/erlang/otp/wiki/Submitting-patches

Comment: No it is because of commit message parsing. Check this unrelated repository https://github.com/webmaster128/dummy-github-ref-test The commit is referenced here: https://github.com/randombit/botan/pull/386